# Htaccess Yii 2 Configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2

I am working on a Yii2 Project and have set it up on Wamp Localhost. My Wamp I have set up an alias:

```
Alias /project "c:/Users/Shaun/Desktop/projects/project/web/" 

<Directory "c:/Users/Shaun/Desktop/projects/project/web/">
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

In a basic app I have placed the htaccess file into the web directory (where it is currently pointing to)

> project/web/.htaccess
>
> project/web/index.php
>
> project/web/index-test.php

mod_rewrite is definitely enabled I have checked. I can navigate to my root without a problem:

This is my htaccess file as demonstrated on Yii2 docs.

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php


http://localhost/project/
```

When I navigate to url above I hit my SiteController Index action fine. But when I try to go to for example:

```
http://localhost/project/site/index
```

It states:

> The requested URL /Users/Shaun/Desktop/projects/project/web/index.php was not found on this server.

But it is definitely there?! If you see my web.php configuration as a component I have enabled:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ]
```

Still can't find it. But if I do this it shows the routes fine:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/site/index
```

So frustrating as I don't want this. What's the deal here?

Thanks,

Comment: is the rewrite module enabled?

Comment: "mod_rewrite is definitely enabled I have checked"

Comment: my apologies i missed that line in question, this normally happens to me when mod_rewrite is not enabled properly, or .htaccess does not have file permissions set correctly(should not be a problem for you as you are on windows).. try setting the same directly in your apache conf instead of overriding, and restarting the server fully,

Answer (score 3):

Because you are working on the virtual directory (e.g. Alias /site/ "/dir/"), you must use

```
RewriteBase /site/
```

in your apache configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your Project seems a bit unsual.
Is there another project folder in the folder web ?

If the answer is yes, you have to put the .htaccess file in this project folder.

But if the project folder contains web, it's quite unsual. But also in that case, the .htaccess file has to be in the project folder.

Comment: It seems that you haven't read about the problem context. Its Yii 2 related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Set `AllowOverride All` in httpd.conf or your vhost conf.
This is mandatory to work with pretty URLs.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change three files.
basic > .htaccess
basic > web > .htaccess
basic > config > web.php

Use the code given in the below url.

http://www.codematrics.com/htaccess-in-yii2-basic-app/

This will help you.

Comment: Try this in combination with an Apache Alias directive, and you will find out that this is not enough. The RewriteBase is the problem.